# StrongSwan not work with xl2tpd

Tags: networking, server, vpn

I have ubuntu18 with Strongswan and xl2tpd installed. Everything is configed.
I stop the strongswan by command:
service strongswan stop

Tnen I connect server from win97 by L2TP. It works fine. however, any PSK is working. I check the xl2tpd log. seems nothing went to Strongswan(no matter it is started nor stopped)

```
:~# xl2tpd -D
```

xl2tpd[9807]: Enabling IPsec SAref processing for L2TP transport mode SAs

xl2tpd[9807]: IPsec SAref does not work with L2TP kernel mode yet, enabling force userspace=yes

xl2tpd[9807]: setsockopt recvref[30]: Protocol not available

xl2tpd[9807]: Not looking for kernel support.

xl2tpd[9807]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.10 started on ip-172-16-16-24 PID:9807

xl2tpd[9807]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.

xl2tpd[9807]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001

xl2tpd[9807]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002

xl2tpd[9807]: Forked again by Xelerance ([www.xelerance.com](http://www.xelerance.com)) (C) 2006-2016

xl2tpd[9807]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 1701

xl2tpd[9807]: Connection established to 120.230.131.220, 228
32.  Local: 58256, Remote: 192 (ref=0/0).  LNS session is 'default'

xl2tpd[9807]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 192 (got 3, expected 2)

xl2tpd[9807]: handle_packet: bad control packet!

xl2tpd[9807]: result_code_avp: result code not appropriate for Incoming-Call-Request.  Ignoring.

xl2tpd[9807]: start_pppd: I'm running:

xl2tpd[9807]: "/usr/sbin/pppd"

xl2tpd[9807]: "/dev/pts/2"

xl2tpd[9807]: "passive"

xl2tpd[9807]: "nodetach"

xl2tpd[9807]: "10.0.0.1:10.0.0.20"

xl2tpd[9807]: "auth"

xl2tpd[9807]: "require-chap"

xl2tpd[9807]: "name"

xl2tpd[9807]: "xl2tpd"

xl2tpd[9807]: "file"

xl2tpd[9807]: "/etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd"

xl2tpd[9807]: "ipparam"

xl2tpd[9807]: "120.230.131.220"

xl2tpd[9807]: Call established with 120.230.131.220, PID: 9819, Local: 62080, Remote: 1, Serial: 0

below is xl2tpd.conf

[global]

ipsec saref = yes

force userspace = yes

debug tunnel = no

debug avp = no

debug network = no

debug state = no

auth file = /etc/ipsec-secrets

[lns default]

ip range = 10.0.0.20-10.0.0.30

local ip = 10.0.0.1

require chap = yes

require authentication = yes

name = xl2tpd

pass peer = yes

ppp debug = no

pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd

length bit = yes

;unix authentication = yes

below is options.xl2tpd

ipcp-accept-local

ipcp-accept-remote

ms-dns 8.8.8.8

ms-dns 8.8.4.4

require-mschap-v2

noccp

auth

crtscts

idle 1800

mtu 1280

mru 1280

lock

lcp-echo-failure 10

lcp-echo-interval 60

connect-delay 5000

what should I do to make strongswan work?

Answer (score 0):

You mention Win97, I'm not sure which version of Windows you meant, I'm guessing Win7 and not Win98.

In Windows for the L2TP settings, try changing from "Optional encryption (connect even if no encryption)" to "Require encryption (disconnect if the server declines)".

On the Ubuntu 18.04 server in the firewall settings, disable direct L2TP connections so clients are forced to use IPsec to connect first.